# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I´m working with symfony 2.1.2, FOSuserBundle, SonataAdminBundle, SonataUserBundle and SonataMediaBundle. The problem is that I cannot access to my database and get this error.

This is my parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: superlinea
    database_user: root
    database_password: !Admin1234
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: localhost
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: f4c89326a7c2d2fb848e84dc8b39ea92
    database_path: null
```

and this is my config.yml [ doctrine section: ]

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        # auto_mapping: true
        # entity_managers:
        #     default:
        #         mappings:
        #             ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
    dbal:
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
```

I checked to connect to mysql from my terminal using the credentials on parameters.yml and it connects correctly.
I purged the cache and still it isn´t taken the specified password.

Any help?

Comment: Try quoting your password in parameters.yml: `database_password: "!Admin1234"`

Comment: Thx, I tried but still the same error. It seems like it is not reading the config.yml or something

Comment: It seems to recognize your database_user (root), so I guess it reads the config, just misinterprets one of the values. Have you tried fetching `doctrine.dbal` via DI-Container and then reading the config and see if it matches the settings from parameters.yml? The error message indicates a missing password, but maybe it's something else?

Comment: I checkout to another brach where it works. The problem started when I changed config.yml and added "default_connection:   default" and default setting as you can see in the parameters.yml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem is within your config.yml, the

```
dbal:
  types:
    json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
```

should go inside doctrine dbal. Like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
```

Hope it helps

Comment: FOR ANYONE WITH MY PROBLEM: using symfony2.8.9 i was getting the same error page. for some reason in the config.yml file the component *doctrine > dbal > connections > default > driver* was set to **pdo_mysql** as default. Switching it back to **"%database_driver%"** solved it.

Answer (score 2):

In your app/config/parameters.yml

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: "your_password"
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

database_password should be inside double quoted (") or single quoted (').

I have seen most of users happen this because they are using password with leading zero or numeric (in my situation its like that)

---

And also I have tried with localhost and double quoted passwords, its not working.

So in that case use

```
database_host: 127.0.0.1
```

instead of

```
database_host: localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

For all who have this problem, just try to clear the cache:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```