# Symfony Semantical Error - has no field or association

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.2

I'm getting the error in ORM/Symfony:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 73 near 'group = :groupId': Error:
> Class ActGood\CommunityBundle\Entity\GroupReporting has no field or
> association named group

My query is:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('sum(h.hours)')
    ->from('ActGoodCommunityBundle:GroupReporting','h')
    ->where('h.group = :groupId') 
    ->andWhere('h.start >= :start') 
    ->andWhere('h.end <= :end')   
    ->setParameters([
      'groupId' => $group->getId(),
      'start' => $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
      'end' => $end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ])
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Group is defined in `GroupReporting` here:

```
/**
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="group_id")
 */  
private $group;
```

Since this last worked, I've both migrated servers and updated Symfony from 2.2 to 2.8. I've tried clearing cache, checked that orm's auto mapping is on. I think it might be something to do with the join column's syntax - maybe something that changed between the two versions? I've tried adding this:

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity="Group")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is your database updated?

Comment: I haven't changed the structure, though I did migrate - how do I update the database?

Comment: First update the autoloader. "composer install --optimize-autoloader"  Then clear the cache. "bin/console cache:clear --env=dev" For Database update "bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force"

Comment: Thanks, @RamazanApaydın. This is a live site (a project I inherited) so I don't want to change the database. Is there some other ORM cache I can clear somewhere?

Comment: I tried this 'php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql' and got the error 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'' even though my parameters.yml file has my (non-root) mysql password.. ideas there?

Comment: Back up your database and try. You need to force the database update (--force). Doctrine for cache https://stackoverflow.com/a/11826487/2210147

Comment: Okay. I still have to figure out why it's not getting my password correctly from parameters.yml (see previous comment) - any ideas there?

Comment: I've tried making sure my password is in quotes everywhere, making the start of it non-numeric, updating localhost to 127.0.0.1, and checking syntax as per the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703989/sqlstate28000-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password - no luck so far.

Comment: I don't understand why it's trying to use root as the user - I have a different user set in my parameters.yml. Does that give any clues?