# My Symfony 3.3 website is displaying blank

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, dbal

When I run my website www.example.com it shows blank. And when I run www.example.com/app_dev.php the following error is displayed.

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Parameters.yml

```
parameters:
database_host: localhost
database_port: null
database_name: mydb
database_user: myuser
database_password: 'Myuser123'
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: mail.smtp2go.com
mailer_user: demo@demo.com
mailer_password: YzA3NTMyY2c1aDkw
secret: d51a96a676b308372c91a26e65ff27cb5eb02e37
```

Till now I have tried following.

```
a. Password: null
b. user: root
```

Cleaned cache several ,but same error.
All privilege is given.

Comment: Maybe you can find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703989/sqlstate28000-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password

Comment: Didn't work....

Comment: Check the login credentials to your database. It seems that it is not correct. Try to validate it logging in manually via some MySQL GUI or terminal.

Comment: Also, have you tried from a command line `mysql -u myuser -p` and then enter the password indicated above, and verify you can login as that user to mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
database_host: localhost
```

into

```
database_host: 127.0.0.1
```

then clear your cache:

```
bin/console c:c --env=dev
bin/console c:c --env=prod
```